Can I use the CJKfonts as math fonts?
The fonts configuration in LaTeX is a little confusing me. In my present knowledge system of LaTeX fonts, because my mother tougne is Chinese, which in my document I have three kinds of fonts to set:

the mainfonts
the CJKfonts
the math-fonts

Although I came across the docs of fntguide and know the five arrtibutes of each fonts:encoding, family, series, shape, size, but I have trouble in classifing them into differernt type with fc-list in command line:
fc-list :lang=en % to list the main fonts
fc-list :lang=zh % to list the CJK fonts

My First Question is : how to list the math-fonts installed in my computer could be assign as the math fonts in command line?
Moreover, if I get three list of fonts(mainfont,CJKfonts,mathfonts), how could I assign them into three categories command(setmainfont,setsansfont,setmonofont), how could I get the detailed infomation of fonts.
My Second Question is: could I assigned a font name 'xxxxFontMono' as the sansfont, or use the CJKfonts like 'Microsoft Yahei' as the mathfonts? In other word, could I assign the font-family mixed?
As for my final question, I want to replica the following PDF:

Although the edited above is via Microsoft Word, but I tried to replica it in XeLaTeX.
My OS is Windows 11 professional, with TeXLive2024, XeLaTeX.
Some infomation is as below:

The title is \zihao{4} and \yahei  with the ctex package
The mathfonts, as the MSoffice set, is also the Microsoft YaHei fonts with \zihao{5}, but as the Question 2 mentioned, I don't know that is it reasonable to assign the CJKfonts as mathfont with unicode-math, or the MSoffice just automatically substituted another math fonts to fixed the case.

How could I get the basic fonts configured tutorial like fntguide for basically configured the fonts, fonts actually mess me in learning LaTeX. thanks!
Any other infomation of the PDF is needed I will supplement them as soon as possible.
Here below is updated with the font information in the formula.



I'm not sure what math fonts have been installed on your system. You can run fc-list | grep math on the terminal to have a look.
However, in the texmf tree (texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public) there are some math fonts:

lete-sans-math (previous name is lato-math)
euler-math
lm-math
xcharter-math
garamond-math
etc.

They can be used together with the unicode-math package.

You can set sans-type or mono-type fonts in the argument of \setmainfont (It's your choice but this kind of practice is quite uncommon). If you are using unicode-math, you must choose some OpenType math font.
If you set some CJK font as the math font, such as \setmathfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}, fontspec will issue the following warning:
Package unicode-math Warning: The first font loaded by unicode-math must be an
(unicode-math)                OpenType Math font (with script=math). If you
(unicode-math)                simply want ‘the default’ before loading
(unicode-math)                supplementary fonts over the top for certain
(unicode-math)                ranges, use: 
(unicode-math)                \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

and the math in use is Latin Modern Math.



Okay, that is to said the CJK font couldn't be set as math fonts in LaTeX(Actually it sound werid).  so, if I have the PDF file, and the formula is displayed at the picture in the problem, and via the pdf-editor I know that the formula font-name is CID-font6 . Could I have any chance to replica the font and the integral symbol in LaTeX.

I also have another doubt about, is there any method to classify a font to be mono/sans or neither of them, is there any command could we classify the font family. And what will happened if I set the FandolSong-Mono as the sanif font?

It's hard to say since I don't have CIDFont+F6 on my machine.

Actually the ·CIDFont familyis actually the namedMicrosoft YaHeiis commonly seen in Windows System,may be? I just a little curious the math symbols style set asMicrosoft YaHei`.
